# Applying 2D convolution to multichannel image

Tags: conv-neural-network, mean, convolution

I have a single-channel image and want to make it multichannel by corrupting it with various sources of noise. Let's say the end dimension is [height , width , number_of_corrupted_copies]. How can I apply a 2D convolution to this and get a single image, with 1 channel? What I want is to convolve in depth and take averages over identical patches in all copies of the image, which have been corrupted differently.